# how to plot a graph in a def igraph-python

Tags: python, function, igraph

I need help to plot a graph in a `def` using igraph in python, when the code isn't in a def it works, but when i put it in one def, like `draw_graph(5)` and call the function
nothing happens.

```
#code 1

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import igraph as ig
    
def draw_graph(vertex_num): 
    g = ig.Graph()
    g.add_vertices(vertex_num)

    layout = g.layout("kk")
    visual_style = {}
    visual_style["vertex_size"] = 20
    visual_style["layout"] = layout
    visual_style["bbox"] = (300, 300)
    visual_style["margin"] = 20
    
    return (g, visual_style)

#main
name = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
option = '1'
if option == '1':
    g,visual_style = draw_graph(5)
    ig.plot(g, **visual_style)
```

In this code above, the graph doesn't appear, but in the next code the graph appear:

```
#code 1

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import igraph as ig
    
def draw_graph(vertex_num): 
    g = ig.Graph()
    g.add_vertices(vertex_num)

    layout = g.layout("kk")
    visual_style = {}
    visual_style["vertex_size"] = 20
    visual_style["layout"] = layout
    visual_style["bbox"] = (300, 300)
    visual_style["margin"] = 20
    
    return (g, visual_style)

#main
name = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
option = '1'
if option == '1':
    g,visual_style = draw_graph(5)
ig.plot(g, **visual_style)
```

[graph that shows in code 2 and that should appear in code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4ybi.png)

Comment: `len(num)` is improper as ints don't have lengths, so you may want to change that just to `num`.  Is the function supposed to print something because plot just returns something to the function but not out of the function to access the object outside of the function you should have `return plot(g, **visual_style)`. That may fix the problem though unsure on where the function call is being used.

Comment: len(num) was a mistake in the example, but even with the return it doesn't show. Can i plot the graph in a function or just in main? Because even if the graph was inside a while, for example, it doesn't show

Comment: you should be able to plot the graph in both. Can you give more context on what you did originally and what you are doing with the function call currently?

Comment: i edited my question with a pic and two codes for more context, do i have to use plt.show()?